# How can I hide jsFiddle panels?

Tags: jsfiddle

I'd like to show pure JavaScript examples in jsFiddle, and I only need a JavaScript window and a console.  I've figured out how to get a console window to appear, but is there a way to remove the HTML and CSS windows?  Is there a better service than jsFiddle to use for my needs?

Comment: I don't believe you can hide the panels on JSFiddle. Maybe check out jsbin.com - it has a built-in console and you can toggle which panes you want.

Comment: That seems to be the case.  I couldn't find a way to remove them.

Answer (score 23):

As of December 4th, 2016 hiding and showing panels was set as an accepted idea in [jsfiddle's development roadmap](https://trello.com/c/XwX7xzTK/47-ability-to-show-and-hide-specific-editor-panels). As of today that's as far as it's got so you'd need to use something else like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [codepen](http://codepen.io). Maybe give it an upvote in their roadmap to put some pressure on ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem.
Since JSFiddle doesn't hide panels and the default build-in console position is annoying you can try a workaround(see attached image)

1. In JSFIDDLE set the result panel position to the bottom.
2. in JSFIDDLE Minimize CSS, minimize the HTML
3. Open the console of the browser on the right - instead of the one built-in in JSFIDDLE!

enjoy this setup[image: JSFiddle -setup for javascript only]